# argument passed to call that takes no argument

Tags: arrays, swift, tree

I am new to Swift and coding so I am sorry if this is a stupid question but this error comes up when I test my code.
My code is:

```
class Node {
  var value: String
  var children = [Node]()
  init() {   
  value = " "
  }
}
```

The error message said:

```
main.swift:29:21: error: argument passed to call that takes no arguments
let m0= Node(value:"wash")
```

And this is my instruction:

```
1. Edit a file named "main.swift"                                                  
2. Create a class called Node                                                   
3. Do not specify access modifiers
4. Create a property called "value" of type string                                
5. Create a property called "children" of type array of Nodes
6. Create a default constructor which initializes value to an empty string and children to an empty array
7. Create a constructor which accepts a parameter named value and assigns it to the appropriate property
```

Comment: Hint: you haven't done step 7 yet. Also, make sure you have a space before your `=` in your `let m0` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to make a constructor (init function) which accept a parameter (step 7), this is why the error states the call takes no arguments. By adding the `value` parameter, we can accept it and then assign it to the corresponding variable.

```
class Node {
  var value: String
  var children = [Node]()

  init() {
      value = ""
      children = [Node]()
  }

  init(value: String) {   
    self.value = value
  }
}

let m0 = Node(value: "wash")
```

Comment: The OP's instruction list implies that there should be two different constructors.

Comment: Good catch, I've edited my answer.